# Can you kick a Pokémon from a rivaling Gym by lowering the Gym level?

Tags: pokemon-go

If you battle at a Gym you'll earn some XP for each Pokémon trainer you defeat at the Gym even if you can't beat all the trainers at the Gym. Per win the Gym will also loose some of its prestige.

As the level (and maximum number of occupying Pokémon) of the Gym is related to this amount of prestige, is it possible to lower the Gym's level and effectively booting out one of the occupying Pokémon in case the maximum number of occupants is exceeded?

For example. Let's say you'd battle at a Level 3 Gym that has 3 Pokémon stationed at it. If you would keep on winning fights up to the point the Gym level would lower to 2, would one of the Pokémon (presumably the one with the lowest CP) be removed from the Gym?

Comment: Not only is it possible, it is actually the purpose. Why else would you battle a gym?

Comment: FYI, since the recent gym rework, I don't believe this question any longer has relevance.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Yes, if you defeat a Pokemon multiple times and the [Gyms level goes down](http://www.pokemon-go-wiki.com/Gyms), the weaker ones get kicked out.

Answer (score 10):

There are prestige levels which gives the gym it's level, and you can have 1 slot per level. Also adding a pokemon to a gym gives +2000 prestige.

- 2000
- 4000
- 8000
- 12,000
- 16,000
- 20,000
- 30,000
- 40,000
- 50,000

if you go pass a level, the number of slots will change and kick the weakest pokemon if needed.

Exemple a Gym at 8200 prestige with 3 pokemon, looses 2500 and goes down to 5700. It is no longer lvl3 but lvl2, and the weakest pokemon (first on in order of CP) is removed.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, right up until it's level 0 and considered neutral. For each level you lower it, the lowest CP pokemon gets booted from the gym. Once you have it reach level 0, anyone can place a new pokemon into the gym to defend it.